# Random shuffle error message

Tags: python, random

Hi I am writing a Monopoly game simulator and have the following list of
Community Chest Card Nos within a card object :-

```
self.CChcards_MessNo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

I want to shuffle these,with the following method

```
def shuffle(self):
   import random
   random.shuffle(self.CChcards_MessNo)
```

which works early on in the program but fails and gives
the following message later in the main part of the program.

```
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\random.py", line 278, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

This occurs when the program has cycled through the 16 cards and now needs to shuffle the cards

Comment: because `x` is an integer...

Comment: There's code (not shown in your question) that assigns an integer to `CChcards_MessNo`.

Comment: I'm guessing `self.CChcards_MessNo` isn't a list anymore at that point.

Comment: Somewhere else in your program (in code that you haven't posted yet), you have set `self.CChcards_MessNo` to an integer - you've assigned a number to that variable. That's why you get this error. Side note: don't import within a function

Comment: Four different commenters all reaching the same conclusion -- I think we're on to something!

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class Foo():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.CChcards_MessNo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
...     def shuffle(self):
...         import random
...         random.shuffle(self.CChcards_MessNo)
...     def bug(self):
...         print("I'm a bug that makes shuffle() fail by assigning an int to self.CChcards_MessNo")
...         self.CChcards_MessNo = 0
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.shuffle()
>>> foo.bug()
I'm a bug that makes shuffle() fail by assigning an int to self.CChcards_MessNo
>>> foo.shuffle()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in shuffle
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 271, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: **TL;DR**: Somewhere in your code your assigning `self.CChcards_MessNo`.

Comment: ^ is being set to an integer.

Comment: Yes  I had set that to an integer!!  Thankyou all repliers.   I was stumped by the error message -- relating presumably to a line in the shuffle module.